# Error en onCreate android .AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView cannot be cast to com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditTextat

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Tengo el siguiente error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: shop.easy.app.x.com.x, PID: 10183
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shop.easy.app.x.com.x/shop.easy.app.x.com.x.Acceso}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView cannot be cast to com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView cannot be cast to com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  at shop.easy.app.x.com.x.Acceso.onCreate(Acceso.java:35)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Específicamente en esta parte**

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView cannot be cast to com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditTextat shop.easy.app.x.com.x.Acceso.onCreate(Acceso.java:35)

**El Codigo Acceso.xml**

```
    package shop.easy.app.x.com.x;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import shop.easy.app.x.com.x.Common.Common;
import shop.easy.app.x.com.x.model.Usuario;

public class Acceso extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtPhone,edtPassword;
    Button btnSignIn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);



        //init firebase

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("Usuario");

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(Acceso.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Por favor espera...");
                mDialog.show();

                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        //comprobar si el usuario no existe en la base de datos
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

                            //Informacion usuario

                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(Usuario.class);
                            if (usuario.getContraseña().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                                {
                                    Intent homeintent = new Intent(Acceso.this,Inicio.class);
                                    Common.currentUsuario =  usuario;
                                    startActivity(homeintent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Acceso.this, "Constraseña incorrecta !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Acceso.this, "Usuario no registrado en base de dato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**código xml**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangulo_trans_blanco"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:text="Usuario"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/barratrasparente"
        android:hint="958439457"
        android:paddingStart="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:text="Contraseña"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/barratrasparente"
        android:hint="********"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="0sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:text="¿Recordar Contraseña?"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/botonestilo1"
        android:text="Iniciar Seción"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/botonestilo2"
        android:text="Registrarse"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="¿Olvidaste tu contraseña? restablecer aquí"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


</LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas instanciando variables de tipo `EditText` con instancias de tipo `MaterialEditText`.

> con el método `findVIewById()` lo que haces es obtener la instancia de un objeto.

Para solucionar tu problema las variables deben ser del mismo tipo que las instancias.

```
EditText edtPhone,edtPassword; ❌ incorrecto
MaterialEditText edtPhone, edtPassword; ✔ correcto
```

#### Editada

El problema es que estas haciendo casting de objetos de tipo `MaterialEditText` con objetos de tipo `EditText`.

> Esto es casting `(MaterialEditText)`

La solución al problema es hacer casting de tipo `EditText`

```
edtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
```

---

> Ojo: `MaterialEditText` y `EditText` no son el mismo tipo de objeto.

Comment: cambia el codigo pero igualmente me da el error en la parte de                                 
        edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

Comment: Agrega el layout de la actividad a la pregunta.

Comment: ok, ya esta agregado c;

Comment: Tienes un elemento tipo `AutoCompleteTextView` con el Id `edtPhone` y sin embargo en tu clase lo declaras como EditText y ademas, el cast lo estas haciendo con `MaterialEditText`por eso te sigue devolviendo ese error.

Comment: @Neil he editado mi respuesta.

Comment: @David Gracias si hay estaba el problema ahora todo funciona ok, gracias..